# Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Construct'. - AWS Open Search Serverless

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, opensearch

I get this error when I pass the `Construct` instance to the `CfnCollection` constructor.

```
import { Construct } from "@aws-cdk/core";
import { CfnCollection, CfnSecurityPolicy} from '@aws-cdk/aws-opensearchserverless';

export interface CloudSearchConstructProps {
  name: string;
}

export class CloudSearchConstruct extends Construct {
  public readonly searchDomain: string;

  constructor(scope: Construct, readonly id: string,) {
    super(scope, id);

    const collection = new CfnCollection(this, 'postCollection', {
      name: 'post-collection',
      type: 'SEARCH'
    });
```

I have looked at similar questions on StackOverflow, but the causes of their problems were different.

There is no mismatch between the versions

```
"@aws-cdk/aws-opensearchserverless": "^1.202.0",
"@aws-cdk/core": "1.202.0",
```

Also, I'm using node version `v14.20.0` to install the node modules

Comment: Have you checked your version lock file to confirm that versions are not mismatched? It looks in `^1.202.0` you actually might be getting a version higher than that.